# Circuit for Inverse Chebyshev or Elliptic LPF

Tags: circuit-analysis, sallen-key

I know I came across a 2 op-amp, 2 capacitor circuit that can be used for a single section of an Inverse Chebyshev (a.k.a. "Chebyshev Type II) or an Elliptic (Cauer) filter.  It has a pair of zeros on the \$j\omega\$-axis at \$\pm j\omega_z\$, and with resonant frequency \$\omega_0<\omega_z\$ and the transfer function is:

$$ H(s) = \frac{1 + \left(\tfrac{s}{\omega_z}\right)^2 }{1+\tfrac{1}{Q}\tfrac{s}{\omega_0}+\left(\tfrac{s}{\omega_0}\right)^2} $$

I know how to brute force derive a circuit with a pair of integrators and the canonical form we learned in Linear Circuits class 4 decades ago.  Such as this:

[image: 2nd-order canonical]

I just thought I saw a more elegant circuit, with one less op-amp and a couple fewer resistors, that pretty much guaranteed that the zeros lie on the \$j\omega\$-axis and at a higher frequency than the resonant frequency \$\omega_0\$.  Anybody know how to save a couple of parts with this?  Is there a single op-amp, two-capacitor, 4-resistor circuit that can do this?

A sorta Sallen-Key with zeros.

Comment: I'm so ashamed of myself.  4 decades ago, I would know this.  But I can't remember this now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several one-opamp circuits with Chebyshev II or Cauer behaviour, for example:

- double-T-feedback circuits with positive (fixed) gain,
- Boctor-filter (based on Multi-feedback topology),
- Scultety-structure
- GIC-based structures

(Hint: Google for Boctor and Scultety)

For example, see here:

[http://www.schematica.com/active_filter_resources/a_list_of_active_filter_circuit_topologies.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20180724224348/http://www.schematica.com/active_filter_resources/a_list_of_active_filter_circuit_topologies.html)

Comment: my goodness, what a useful link!  i had never heard of schematica.com before.

Comment: looks to me that the Boctor might be the one.  (i don't want more storage elements than the order of the filter, so the double T is less preferred.)

Comment: Yes - another point: Double-T is very sensitive to component tolerances (exact matching required). In this respect, GIC structures are best - however with two opamps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering, will this do it?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f30DVQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: doing the node-voltage method now.  what an interesting trip down memory lane.

Comment: Why not simulate it?

Comment: i wanna transfer function.

Comment: Well you can try this circuit or that circuit and derive the TF for each and examine the TF to see if it matches or you can just mess around with a sim until you get the TF looking about right then derive it. It's your time you'll be spending.

Comment: i want something that relates R1, R2, R3, R4, C1, and C2 to \$Q\$, \$\omega_0\$, and \$\omega_z\$.

Comment: i just gotta slug out this node-voltage analysis.

Comment: Cascading a notch filter with a sallen key will do the job

Comment: two capacitors.

Comment: This opamp circuit only has one zero, so it can't realize the transfer function in the question.

Comment: thanks for confirming what it appeared to me to be, @SvenB.